# is it true that finite groups with unique maximal subgroups are cyclic?

Tags: group-theory

Assume that $G$ is a finite group. For any prime $p\mid |G|$, $G$ has a unique maximal subgroup of index $p$, is it true that $G$ is  a cyclic group or direct product of quaternion of order 8?

Comment: No it is not true, there are noncyclic groups with that property. I can think of one of order $24$.

Comment: are you sure about group of order 24?

Comment: @DerekHolt: The question says for each prime dividing $|G|$; not sure what group you are thinkng about.

Comment: This is true for $p$-groups, so it would be enough to show your group is nilpotent.  But I'm not there yet.

Comment: $A_4 \times C_2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The group $G = A_4 \times C_2$ has unique subgroups of index $2$ and $3$, namely $A_4$ and $C_2^3$.

Another example is $A_6 \times C_{15}$.

Comment: Thinking is the  greatest mathematician art. Thanks